# jquery function to search array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

I have a structure like this:

```
var var1 = { 
     array1 : ['value1','value2', ...],
     array2 : ['value3','value4', ...]
     ...
};
```

I need a javascript function to search values in this structure, and if exists,
this function will return the name of the array.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Not only that you don't show any research effort at all, your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Damn! I love challenges to much! I wrote an answer to this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function find(value, obj) {
    for (var x in obj) {
        if ($.inArray(value, obj[x]) >= 0) {
            return (x);
        }
    }
}

var var1 = {
    array1: ['value1', 'value2'],
    array2: ['value3', 'value4'],
    array3: ['value5', 'value6']
};

var value = 'value3';

alert(find(value, var1));​    ​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnBCx/1)

Comment: gdoron, jslint shows a error in line 2.
I'm searching for a fix in this moment.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @rabugento. It's a bug of jsLint... forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var var1 = { 
     array1: ['value1', 'value2'],
     array2: ['value3', 'value4']
};

function search( obj, val ) {

    var arr,
        name;

    for ( var i in obj ) {

        if ( typeof obj[i] === "object" && obj[i] instanceof Array ) {

            arr = obj[i];

            arr.forEach(function( a ) {

                if ( a === val ) name = i;

            });

        }

    }

    return name;

}

search( var1, 'value4' ); // array2
```

Comment: your code works, thanks!

Comment: Please click the check if it worked. I'm glad it helped!